# Nodejs request : REST API call inside REST API

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-request

I am developing a REST API Framework. The  client will call a my end point using POST. My code then will make an additional call to an external system using POST. But, I am running into issues with the request library. Look at my code snippet below.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
var mydb;

app.post("/token", function (req, response) {
    console.log("Call to /token");
    var token = "a"
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    var options = {
        url: 'https://xyz/oauth2//token',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        json: {
            'key1': 'xxx',
            'key2': 'yyy'
        }
    }
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        } else {
            console.log(body)
        }
    })
    return response.send(token)
```

The return will always be 'a' because of the async nature of the request  method.
How to return the right value everytime?

Comment: Can you please edit your code to fix the indentation and to remove the double spacing so we can read it better here on stack overflow.

Comment: token is never reassigned in your code. Therefor it will always be "a" as declared at the top: var token = "a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You understand the problem, the next step is easy. call `res.send` inside your callback, like this below:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Print out the response body
    console.log(body)
    res.send(body)
  } else {
    console.log(body)
  }
})
```

And remove the return from the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you do not reassign value of `token` variable in the code sample you've posted, so it will always be `a`. Please elaborate on what you want to achieve, what you want to have in `token` variable and what do you want to do with it? I'll be glad to help.